# MetaPost to PDF in Texmaker (miktex)

Tags: miktex, texmaker, windows, metapost

I am trying to make the MPost command in Texmaker work. I am using the Texmaker in windows 7 with miktex.

So far I used the example document below. When using the windows console I was able to use following command for convertnig the .mp file to a pdf (a frient told me to rename the pdf because the previewer of texmaker only reads pdfs with the same name as the input file):

```
mptopdf testfile.m && ren testfile-mps.pdf testfile.pdf
```

This command works great in the console, but when I tried to use it in Texmaker it didn't work anymore:

```
mptopdf %.mp && ren %-mps.pdf %.pdf
```

When using just

```
mptopdf %.mp
```

The pdf testfile-mps.pdf is being generated but when pressing "view PDF" texmaker says 'file not found'.

To my questions:

- So how can I make the rename command work properly?
- Or can I make texmaker showing the *-mps.pdf file?
- What is the command for automatically showing a pdf in texmaker? (So you only have to press one button for compiling and previewing)

Here my testdocument *testfile.mp*

```
outputtemplate:="%j.mps";
beginfig(1);
z1=(0,0);
z2=(10mm,10mm);
drawarrow(z1--z2);
label.ulft(btex $A$ etex, .5[z1,z2]);
endfig;
bye
```